# Como repassar o valor de uma "$variavel" vinda de outra página, e utiliza-la em um select PDO

Tags: php, pdo, select

Seguinte, primeiro gostaria de saber se é possível receber de outra página, através de um `session_start()`, o valor de uma variável e aplica-lo em um select.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

No inicio da página onde quero adicionar o select, eu adicionei o `session_start()`.
Logo em seguida, adicionei o comando `echo $_SESSION['user']` mais abaixo no na página junto ao HTML e até ai, tudo bem, imprimiu o conteúdo da variável da tela.

Logo abaixo no HTML vem o select:

```
select unidade from unidades_administrativas A
join users B on A.id = B.id_unidades
where B.user = '{COMO PASSAR O VALOR de $_SESSION['user'] AQUI???}'
```

Obs.: O objetivo deste select é exibir a unidade do usuário que estiver logado no sistema.

Então minha dúvida é: Como passar o valor desta variável para o select utilizando PDO?

---

Ocorreram os seguintes erros após ter utilizado o seu código:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'Usuário 1'' at line 3 in C:\wamp\www\ponto_eletronico\add_txt_list_unidades.php on line 321

Comment: Se passar `$_SESSION['user']` ele da undefined index?

Comment: Ele simplesmente não retorna nada, nem mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0):

tenta o seguinte:

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("select unidade from unidades_administrativas A
join users B on A.id = B.id_unidades
where B.user = :usuario;");
$consulta->bindParam(':usuario', $_SESSION['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->execute();
$linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Christopher, ocorreram os seguintes erros após ter utilizado o seu código:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'Usuário 1'' at line 3' in C:\wamp\www\ponto_eletronico\add_txt_list_unidades.php on line 321

Comment: me parece que acabou ficando os dois sinais de = = , retire um por favor antes do :usuario

Comment: o "Usuário 1" é sua key de busca? Evite espaços em branco e de um echo e post como esta ficando sua sintaxe antes do execute para avaliar melhor.

Comment: Christopher, 
após suas dicas, percebi que estava utilizando a variável errada!
Ao rodar o select, utilizei a $_SESSION['user_name'] ao invés de $_SESSION['user'].
Por isto estava retornando o {Usuário 1}.
Com $_SESSION['user']. retornou = usuário1.( sem espaços).

Comment: Christopher, 
após suas dicas, percebi que estava utilizando a variável errada!
Ao rodar o select, utilizei a $_SESSION['user_name'] ao invés de $_SESSION['user'].
Por isto estava retornando o {Usuário 1}.
Com $_SESSION['user']. retornou = usuário1.( sem espaços).
Acredito que agora o select esta ok.

Queria testa-lo, imprimindo a variável na tela através de um while(caso o usuario1 esteja cadastrado em mais de uma unidade)
<?php
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "UNIDADE:". $linha['A.unidade'];
}
?> 
So que não retorna nada!

Comment: RESOLVIDO!
Obrigado pela ajuda!